# Throwing error does not show in response apollo

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

Ok so basically Im throwing a std error as such `throw new Error('test')` and have tried throwing this with ApolloError & GraphQLError. I have even tried returning new error with nothing in the response. Also this stops my server which I do not want.

when throwing the error the error is in only the console (server side) and the response returns 200 with something like this

sent (all vars are sent)

```
mutation Cprofile($input: ProfileInput) {
  cprofile(input: $input) {
    bg

  }
}
```

response

```
{
  "data": {
    "stackoverflow": null
  }
}
```

running apollo server like so

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: createContext
});
```

please note ive tried format error

package.json

```
"apollo-server-core": "^3.10.3",
"apollo-server-express": "^3.10.3",
```

Is there any way show error in response in apollo with typescript thanks

Comment: Can you show your client code as well? Normally an Apollo or GraphQL error is returned as a separate `error` key in the response. Also what version of Apollo-Server? 3 and 4 handle errors differently.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I am using apollo 3.10 currently